# onLocationChanged is not called in Galaxy S3 with android 4.1.1

Tags: java, android

This code work fine in other mobiles and also work fine in the samsung galaxy s3 with android 4.0.3 but in Samsung Galaxy S3 with android 4.1.1 dosen't work, any idea?

The problem is that onLocationChanged method is not called never.

The provider returned is "network"

```
/**
* @see android.app.Application#onCreate()
*/
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = getLocationProvider();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 20, locationListener);
}

/**
* @see android.location.LocationListener
*/
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       currentLocationUser = location;
       if (onLocationListener != null) {
            onLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
       }
    }

   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

   } 

   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

   }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
 };

public String getLocationProvider() {
    Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
    locationCriteria.setAccuracy();
    return locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest by using `LocationManager.removeUpdates()` before requesting updates with a new timing. **After JELLYBEAN(4.1) the minimum time between updates is no longer just a hint.**

See [Location manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) for more Informations regarding this.

As Said by Documentation as Below

> **Prior to Jellybean**, the minTime parameter was only a hint, and some
>   location provider implementations ignored it. **From Jellybean and
>   onwards it is mandatory for Android compatible devices to observe both
>   the minTime and minDistance parameters.**

Comment: @Bravesh Thanks for your response, unfortunately there is no LocationManager.removeUpdates() but LocationManager.removeUpdates(listener). How would remove updates for a listener that has not yet subscribed change this behavior?. I have tried it just in case and the LocationListener is never invoked on any of its implemented methods.